# TortoiseSVN setup with Windows Server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-server-2008, installation

I have a Windows Server 2008 and I want to use TortoiseSVN as my source control. I am having some trouble setting everything up. I am assuming I need to install TortoiseSVN on the server and also for every user who will be pushing changes to the server.

My question is, do I also need to install subversion on the server and the users computers as well? Any guidelines on how to set this up would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server end of SVN isn't in TortoiseSVN.  Instead, install VisualSVN Server http://www.visualsvn.com/server/ or any of the other Subversion Windows builds like CollabNet's.  Pretty much all of them are free.

Comment: So I need to install both TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN server on the windows server and on the user systems?

Comment: You need only install VisualSVN Server on the windows server, and you need only install TortoiseSVN on the user systems.